# variation metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

$\newcommand{\Tr}{\operatorname{Tr}}$(I asked this on physicsexchange but no reply)

I have the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. I want to make the variation of $\sqrt{-g}$ where $g=\det g_{\mu\nu}$.

Can I make this work?

\begin{align}
\sqrt{-g} & =\sqrt{-e^{\Tr(\log(g_{\mu\nu}))}}=\sqrt{-e^{-\Tr(\log(g^{\mu\nu}))}} \rightarrow\delta\sqrt{-g} \\[10pt]
& =\delta \left(\sqrt{-e^{-\Tr(\log(g^{\mu\nu}))}} \right)=\delta \left(-e^{-\frac{1}{2}\Tr(\log(g^{\mu\nu}))}\right) \\[10pt]
& =e^{-\frac{1}{2}\Tr(\log(g^{\mu\nu}))}\delta\left(-\frac{1}{2} \Tr(\log(g^{\mu\nu}))\right) =-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}\delta g^{-1} \Tr((\log(g^{\mu\nu}))) \\[10pt]
& =-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}\Tr(g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu})=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}
\end{align}

(but there is this problem of notation, I write $\Tr(g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu})$)

Comment: [Jacobi's equation is sufficiently well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Derivation), why are you trying to do it yourself using a method that requires much, much more machinery?